# Direct constuction of nonlow noncomplete c.e. sets

Tags: logic, computability

How can one construct a noncomplete nonlow c.e. set?

(Background: I've been trying to construct, as an exercise, a nonlow low$_2$ set, but I do not know what kind of requirement is adequate for nonlowness, and I thought a simple example would help.  I searched Odifreddi Vol 2, Soare  but in vain.  I know how to indirectly achieve nonlowness, e.g., by making it high, but that's not applicable to the exercise.)

A pointer to a construction or the construction itself will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jump inversion** is your friend here, and gets you all the way to the problem you mention.

The *Sacks jump inversion theorem* (there are other jump inversion theorems, the *Friebderg* and the *Shoenfield* being the most common) states that for any $x\ge_T0'$ which is c.e. in $0'$, there is some c.e. $y$ such that $y'\equiv_Tx$. The proof is an infinite injury argument, but definitely one of the easier ones.

Meanwhile, any of the usual constructions of a low noncomputable set (Friedberg-Muchnik, low simple set, etc.) relativize to produce a low-over-$0'$ set - that is, an $x$ which is c.e. in $0'$, $>_T0'$, and such that $x'\equiv_T0''$.

Combining these two facts immediately yields a low$_2$, nonlow c.e. degree. Note that we can easily modify this argument to get a low$_3$ c.e. degree which is nonlow$_2$, etc.

---

By the way, for a really sweet example of jump inversion combined with the recursion theorem, check out Sacks' shiny little box: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-01/S0002-9939-1967-0207558-7/S0002-9939-1967-0207558-7.pdf. Sacks gives an elementary(ish) proof of a theorem originally due to Lachlan and Martin, that there is a c.e. set which is neither high$_n$ nor low$_n$ for any $n\in\omega$.